# How to show bash output in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bash

I got this output from AXE library with JEST during my test. I want to show the result in my webpage, the result looks like:

```
Error: [2mexpect([22m[31mreceived[39m[2m).toHaveNoViolations([22m[32mexpected[39m[2m)[22m

Expected the HTML found at $('div:nth-child(2) > .FareListContainer.fr-position-relative[data-testid="fareListContainer"] > .fr-position-relative > .fr-no-gutters.fr-mb-2.fr-row > .fr-col > .fr-clearfix[data-testid="FareSimpleSorting"] > .fr-float-right > .fr-custom-select-container.fr-rounded-\@theme\:card\.rounded-x.fr-border > select') to have no violations:

<select id="fare-simple-sorting-123456789" class="fr-form-control fr-custom-select" aria-label="Press the UP/Down Arrow key to choose a sorting criteria, press the Enter key to select the item or press the TAB key to continue" aria-describedby="fare-simple-sorting-description-123456789" data-testid="simpleSortingSelect">

Expected the HTML found at $('div:nth-child(2) > .FareListContainer.fr-position-relative[data-testid="fareListContainer"] > .fr-position-relative > .fr-no-gutters.fr-mb-2.fr-row > .fr-col > .fr-clearfix[data-testid="FareSimpleSorting"] > .fr-float-right > p') to have no violations:

<p id="fare-simple-sorting-description-123456789" class="fr-sr-only" aria-hidden="true">Your are in the Fare Simple Sorting</p>

Received:

[31m"IDs used in ARIA and labels must be unique (duplicate-id-aria)"[39m

Try fixing it with this help: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/duplicate-id-aria?application=axeAPI

────────

Expected the HTML found at $('div:nth-child(2) > .FareListContainer.fr-position-relative[data-testid="fareListContainer"] > .fr-text-left.fr-font-size-3-x.fr-disclaimer') to have no violations:

<div class="fr-text-left fr-font-size-3-x fr-disclaimer" id="123456789" data-testid="disclaimer"><span>*Fares presented below are available at the beginning of each day, but may sell out. Additional baggage fees and fees for other services may apply. Other terms and conditions may apply</span></div>

Received:

[31m"id attribute value must be unique (duplicate-id)"[39m

Try fixing it with this help: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/duplicate-id?application=axeAPI

────────

Expected the HTML found at $('div:nth-child(2) > .FareListContainer.fr-position-relative[data-testid="fareListContainer"] > .fr-position-relative > .fr-no-gutters.fr-mb-2.fr-row > .fr-col > .fr-clearfix[data-testid="FareSimpleSorting"] > .fr-float-right > .fr-custom-select-container.fr-rounded-\@theme\:card\.rounded-x.fr-border > select') to have no violations:

<select id="fare-simple-sorting-123456789" class="fr-form-control fr-custom-select" aria-label="Press the UP/Down Arrow key to choose a sorting criteria, press the Enter key to select the item or press the TAB key to continue" aria-describedby="fare-simple-sorting-description-123456789" data-testid="simpleSortingSelect">

Received:

[31m"Form elements must have labels (label)"[39m

Try fixing it with this help: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/label?application=axeAPI
    at toHaveNoViolations (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/src/components/containers/FareListContainer/FareListContainer.test.js:27:42)
    at tryCatch (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/home/yoandry/Documents/airmodules/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
```

I want to show text formatted without those characters "[31m" for example. I tried with Prims but is not working for me.

Comment: can provide an example of **exactly** the type of output you want?  The more info and context you give us, the better we can help you.

Comment: @Peter I was trying to show that information just like in Linux terminal, but at this time I'll be happy showing the message without those characters something human readable

Comment: Try piping the output through `cat`: `something jest something | cat`